# How do I call a Custom Function in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I've created a custom function in JMeter that returns a n length string with random characters. Where should I define the function, and how do I call it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your function is in the jmeter classpath, you should be able to call it just like any standard function with `${...}` syntax, as  described [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#how).

Do make sure your jar file containing your function is in `lib/ext`, or added to the jmeter classpath via `search_path`'s input option

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a beanshell script or via a javascript call. See the manual on

[functions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and on [the beanshell preprocessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor).